# How to select gridboxes near a coordinate (with a condition)

Tags: python, datagrid, coordinates

I would like to select 6-8 grid boxes with a value of "1" close to a coordinate x=19 and y=8.5 (which represents an urban area with value of "0"). The grid boxes I would like to select are marked with "X" in red in the following figure:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDCIP.png)

The projected 2D data is coming from a land surface file of a regional climate model, with coordinates currently projected on a rotated grid (see x, y dimensions in figure).
The value 1 is full land-surface, the values 0-0.9999 are urban/sea fractions, partially mixed with land fractions.

I am using python, xarray and possibly numpy (among others).

I have tried to define a way to select 6-8 grid boxes around the coordinate: x=19 and y=8.5, but I could not get any appropriate selection until now.

Is there a way to select these gridboxes?

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to tackle this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.